# Golang - how to grab from till the end of double quotes - need to grab the UUID

Tags: string, go, substring

So I have a string something like this, which is html content with dynamic Tokens embedded in them. Now I need to capture some token information in a map[string]string, which is key of token name to the UUID.
I can check the string to see if a token that I care about example `emailAppointmentCancellation` is present in this block by using strings.contains method. Now if it contains this token, I need to grab the UUID associated with it, which is till the end of the quotes mark. How can I go about it. Would I need some regex expression for that

```html
<div style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.4; margin: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.4; margin: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Hello This is a friendly reminder about your upcoming appointment with </p><p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.4; margin: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><br></p><p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.4; margin: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Your appointment is: <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">{{Token "Stamps:appointmentDate" .}}</span>, <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">{{Token "Stamps:appointmentTime" .}}</span></p><p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.4; margin: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><br></p><p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.4; margin: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">We appreciate your time and look forward to seeing you then!</p><p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.4; margin: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"><br></p><p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.4; margin: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">Sincerely, <span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">{{Token "Forms:emailAppointmentCancellation:0386DA88-B658-43E8-863C-296A22D732FF" .}}</span><br><br><br></div>
```

Comment: While the chances are low you'd get a false match earlier in your HTML, one should use an HTML parser to extract individual `span` & `div` content and work from there. See: https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/net/html

Answer (score 0):

### Regex

Yeah I think a regex would be an easy solution. I like to use https://regex101.com/ for trying it out.

A simple example: https://regex101.com/r/ioRC6e/1

You can use the regex package from the standard library to compile this.

### String Manipulation

If you can be very certain about the data format, you could also just go through the string and find your keys:

https://goplay.tools/snippet/eRu-sKJr-se

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. This is the regex i used finally

`regx := regexp.MustCompile("Forms:" + v + ":([-0-9a-zA-Z]+)")`
`r := string(regx.Find(data))`

where v = `emailAppointmentCancellation` or any other token that I care about
and data is the string in which i am finding the token.

Comment: Having hyphen (-) place as the first character inside [] bracket means it need not be escaped.